# Symfony ManyToMany no need to persist?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, many-to-many, relational-database

i have 2 entities:

Domain:

```
    class Domain
{

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 191, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: 'domain.name.not_blank')]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Bill::class, inversedBy: 'domains', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Collection $bill;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bill = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Bill>
     */
    public function getBill(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bill;
    }

    public function addBill(Bill $bill): self
    {
        if (!$this->bill->contains($bill)) {
            $this->bill->add($bill);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBill(Bill $bill): self
    {
        $this->bill->removeElement($bill);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And Bill:

```
    class Bill
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $number = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Domain::class, mappedBy: 'bill')]
    private Collection $domains;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->domains = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public function setNumber(string $number): self
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Domain>
     */
    public function getDomains(): Collection
    {
        return $this->domains;
    }

    public function addDomain(Domain $domain): self
    {
        if (!$this->domains->contains($domain)) {
            $this->domains->add($domain);
            $domain->addBill($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDomain(Domain $domain): self
    {
        if ($this->domains->removeElement($domain)) {
            $domain->removeBill($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

BillType form:

```
class BillingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('number', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Numero fattura',]
            ])
            ->add('domains', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Domain::class,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn-success',
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Bill::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set the bill for multiple domains at the same time, so my controller look like this:

```
public function domainBilling(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
    {
        $filters = $this->getFilters($request)['filters'];
        $form = $this->getFilters($request)['form'];

        $dbquery = $doctrine
            ->getRepository(Domain::class)
            ->findAllPaginated($filters)
            ->getQuery();

        $domains = $paginator->paginate(
            $dbquery, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1), /*page number*/
            Domain::perPage, /*limit per page*/
            [
                'defaultSortFieldName' => 'd.name',
                'defaultSortDirection' => 'asc',
            ]
        );

        $billing_form = $this->createForm(BillingType::class);
        $billing_form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($billing_form->isSubmitted() && $billing_form->isValid()) {
            $em = $doctrine->getManager();

            $domains = $billing_form['domains']->getData();
            $bill_number = $billing_form['number']->getData();

            $bill = new Bill();
            $bill->setNumber($bill_number);
            
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Le modifiche sono state effettuate!'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('domain_dashboard');
        }


        return $this->render('Admin/domain_dashboard.html.twig', [
            'billing_form' => $billing_form->createView(),
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'domains' => $domains
        ]);
    }
```

And it's working without calling $em->persist(); on bill or domain and without calling foreach to save every domain. If i persist one of them i find duplicate entry for bill inside db. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You do not need to call `persist` when your entity is in a relation with `cascade=persist`

Comment: Could you show the entire controller function? Are you maybe passing a `Bill` object to the form in `$this->createForm()`?

Comment: @DylanKAS and if i want to edit something in the domain, like the name or a date? i need to call persist?

Comment: @Marleen edited with entire controller.

Comment: You only need to use persist on an entity to, well persist an entity. Which mean generating an ID (primary key) for your entity. You should only persist once, if you retrieve it later with a repository, you can modify it and just flush any changes without persisting it again.

Comment: Your form is creating a new `Bill` object behind the scenes, and then calling `->addDomain()` on it to add each of the selected domains to it. `->addDomain()` also sets the new `Bill` object onto each of those `Domain` objects. The domains are already managed by Doctrine (since they're loaded from the database for display in the form) so Doctrine will save them if they've changed when you call `->flush`. Since they also have `cascade:persist` on their `bill` property, Doctrine will also save the new `Bill` object that's been set on that property.

Comment: The `Bill` object you're creating with `$bill = new Bill(); $bill->setNumber($bill_number);` however, is not being saved by Doctrine, since you have not called `->persist` on that. So that's probably the extra `Bill` you're seeing if you do an extra persist.

Comment: @Marleen thank you for the clarification! It is a good solution of what i'm doing?

Comment: Your solution is fine, but (even though not strictly necessary) I would also manually persist the `Bill` object that's been created by the form: `$bill = $billing_form->getData(); $em->persist($bill);` instead of `$bill = new Bill(); $bill->setNumber($bill_number);` This makes it a bit more clear that a new `Bill` object is being created and saved by this function, in case you need to come back to this code later on and wonder what it's doing.